# Is there any package for atom which autocompletes custom components?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, atom-editor, angular-components

I installed lots of packages to atom including emmet,auto complete HTML,angular and typescript plugins. All standard angular tags gets loaded. But my custom component name don`t get loaded. Do we have a plugin for this ?
This is my HTML file
This is my component ts file

Comment: Custom component names "get loaded" for me.

Comment: @WilliamHampshire what are the packages you installed ?